# WPF DropShadowEffect appears on preview but not at runtime

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

So I implemented the following code within my grid:

```
        <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                      Color="Black"
                      Opacity="1"
                      BlurRadius="30" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
       </Grid.Effect>
```

I can see the shadow appear in the preview; however, when I run it, there is no shadow. So I was wondering if I missed something.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                  Color="Black"
                  Opacity="1"
                  BlurRadius="30" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
    </Grid.Effect>

    <Rectangle Height="350" Width="525" Fill="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

You should see a window with a shadow around the border. Then run it and its gone.

**EDIT:** So all I did was add a margin to the rectangle and the drop shadow appears. I'm assuming the window blocks the drop shadow.

Comment: Works for me, what does the rest of your XAML look like (have you tried a simple project to replicate)? =o

Comment: I created a new project, first used grid.effect (doesn't work), then simply created a rectangle inside the window and added the same effect and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, it may help to see a picture of what you're going for.

Comment: I have a transparent window, with no background (to remove the default window interface). Then I put a rectangle (to fill the application window) to provide the white background for the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a margin to your rectangle like this

```
<Rectangle Margin="10"  Height="350" Width="525" Fill="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

The reason it needs the margin is because the drop shadow effect draws a larger outline than what is in the bounds of the rectangle. If you don't want to use the rectangle and just apply to it your grid then add the margin to your grid instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!