# Is there a way to see DropShadowEffect on designtime?

Tags: wpf

I want to attach a `DropShadowEffect` on a `Border` control. I see it on runtime but not in the designer.

```cs
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="LightGray"
                BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                ClipToBounds="True"
                Width="400"
                Height="100">
            <Border Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="0,10,0,0"
                    Margin="0,-11,0,0">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

It's quite annoying, especially if working on custom control library.

The former and now apparently obsolete `DropShadowBitmapEffect` works on run- and designtime.

**Edit:**
This not a duplicate of other questions like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646717/wpf-dropshadoweffect-appears-on-preview-but-not-at-runtime) as it is quite the opposite problem. The shadow effect appears at runtime, but not in the designer. Just try it out with NET-Framework WPF Project and the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DropShadowEffect appears on preview but not at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646717/wpf-dropshadoweffect-appears-on-preview-but-not-at-runtime)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: It is not a duplicate to the mentioned question. It's the opposite problem.